# Why is my $(this).prop('class') not working?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is what i want: I have multiple `<h3>` tags that are being uses as a link to reveal answers to FAQ's. Also I have added a form in case that the user did not see any question of interest on that page. The link for the form is at the bottom of the page. Now when the user click on the **show form** link I would like the window to scroll down to the bottom. I have done this, however when I click on any of the link the window also scrolls to the bottom. I want when the user clicks only on the **show form** link that the window scrolls.

here is what I have so far:

```
<body>
<?php
$array = array("link 1","link 2","link 3");
foreach($array as $link)
{
    echo "<h3 class='link'>".$link."</h3>";
    echo "<div>";
    //information to be displayed
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
<h3 class="forms">Show Form</h3>
//form information here
</body>
```

here is the javscript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h3').click('bind',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle(500,function(){
            var i = $(this).prop('class');

            if(i == 'forms')
            {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, "slow");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have added an alert to verify my output and when I click on `<h3 class="forms">` the alert is blank but when I click on the others the alert showed "link". Can someone help me figure out why the alert is showing blank when I click on the `<h3 class="forms">` tag?

Comment: `$(document).ready(...` is misspelled. Is it that way in your code as well?

Comment: If you're going after class, you want `.attr` not `.prop` Prop is good for actual properties, like `value`, `className`, etc.

Comment: There is no class property, however there is a className property.

Comment: @G_M that was a misspelling here when I entered it.....

Comment: You can also use `if($(this).hasClass('forms'))...` instead of using `prop()`

Answer (score 2):

You are echoing your LI with the link class, instead of $link.

Also, use

```
if ($(this).hasClass("forms"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` should really only be used when accessing the DOM element's [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element) and not attributes (like `class` or `style`, `width`, etc.). If you want the class, use `.attr('class')` instead (or, as others have mentioned, you can use `.hasClass()` to test (with jQuery) if an element has a specific class aplied).

to follow-up on `.prop` vs `.class`:

```
<a href="#foo" class="foo-class" id="foolink">Foo Bar link</a>

var a = document.getElementById('foolink'),
    $a = $(a);

$a.prop('href') // like directly calling a.href
$a.prop('id')  // again, like directly calling a.id
$a.attr('class') // where as it's actually a.className
```

Comment: The thing is when I click on the links inside the PHP statement it works. The alert showed the class. Its the link that is in HTML that it is not showing the class for and that's what I cannot get, why it is doing that?

Comment: I change the .prop to .attr and the alert is showing **Undefined**